# lghub lua script presskey

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I dont really know how to code lua, i made a script, when "Numlock" is on the script clicks "a" for a random time duration, then releases "a" and it presses "s" for random time. repeats the script until numlock is turned off. it doesnt work tho..

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
   OutputLogMessage("wawa")
   if event == sKeyLockOn("Numlock") then
         repeat
            PressKey("a")
            Sleep(math.random(8700, 8900))
            ReleaseKey("a")
            Sleep(2)
            PressKey("s")
            Sleep(math.random(8700, 8900))
            ReleaseKey("s")
            Sleep(2)
            until not IsKeyLockOn("Numlock")
      end
   end
```

this code doesnt work for some reason, i tried using mouse button instead of numlock but no luck

Comment: NumLock does not generate GHub events (that means Lua script will not start doing smth because you pressed NumLock).  Only mouse buttons (on Logitech mouse) and special G-keys (on Logitech keyboard) generate events.  But if an event is generated (by a mouse button), Lua script can determine whether NumLockLED was ON or OFF at this time moment.